# Compare file1 and file2 but show only new lines which are not in file2

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, diff

I am currently struggling with the task to compare two files. Both files have values which have differences and new lines. Example:

file1:

```
Germany=Munich
Swiss=Bern
Austria=Wien
Italy=Rom
```

file2:

```
Germany=Berlin
Swiss=Bern
Italy=Rom
```

The result of my action should be the following:

outputfile:

```
Austria=Wien
```

How can I achieve to get only lines to my output file which are not already in file2? I am not interested in differences of lines. Just a complete line which is missing.

I already experimented with diff and sdiff but without the desired results.

thanks

Comment: if in file 1 you have
Germany=Munich   
Swiss=Bern   
Austria=Wien   
Italy=Rom   
and in file 2 : 
Germany=Hambourg (for example)   
Swiss=Bern   
Italy=Rom   

what do you wan as result ?

Comment: @angel I assume the OP wants only lines where the first field is not found in file2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}!($1 in a)' file2 file1
Austria=Wien
```

We read entire file2 first indexed at countries. We check if the country is not present in our file1 and print it. This won't give you results of lines which are in file2 but not in file1, but can be adjusted to give you that as well. I am not sure if that is your requirement. If it is then please update your question to reflect all your use-cases for more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me exactly the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about ordering, you can sort the files and then use `join`:

```
sort file1 > file1.srt
sort file2 > file2.srt
join -t'=' -v1 file1.srt file2.srt
```

The flags for `join` specify to use the equals sign as the field separator, include unpairable lines from file1.srt while suppressing the pairable lines from file1.srt.

Comment: Are both `-a1` and `-v1` necessary? The man page makes it sound like you only want `-v1` here.

Comment: @EtanReisner No, I guess it is not. I believe that I misread the man page entry for `-v`. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#([^=]*=).*#/^\1/d#' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Use file2 as the basis for a sed script and run this sed script against file1